# How do i change Chromiums default search engine?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

Im working on a Chromium fork. How do i change the default search engine? I want to change it to DuckDuckGo.

Comment: Solved, edit /components/search_engines/prepopulated_engines.json.

Comment: Better post your solution as the answer to this question. It will be helpful to others in the future who might be looking to do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/components/search_engines/prepopulated_engines.json`